# How to exclude GIT from VPN

Tags: git, vpn

I am using [ExpressVPN](http://expressvpn.com/) in China, to access western internet. Also I use git, but with Chinese servers. When I try to pull/push, it fails or is very slow when connected to VPN. ExpressVPN however enables me to define applications that will be excluded from the VPN connection, unfortunately git itself is not an app, but executable.
Does anybody have some experience in addressing something like this?